# Interface django with c# desktop application

Tags: c#, python, .net, django, http

I have this project where i have a django server which is running on a machine, which is used to communicate with other machines on the network.
Now i also have another application written in c# on the same machine which is used to monitor state of certain hardware.

I want to know if there is a way to write a http request/response system in the c# application  where i can interface it with the django server such that when django makes a request to the c# application it reads certain values and returns a response to Django.

Can someone please tell me how to write this http server on the c# application or give me resources where i can look this up.

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. I would go for a RESTFul web service interface, so search terms (`C# REST`). Just a sample hit: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor).